# Tengo este query con muchas dudas, como aumentarle el 30%? SQL

Tags: mysql

Calcular el precio promedio de compra de los productos y aumentarle el 30% a partir del costo que se calcula, representando ese 30% la utilidad que queremos ganar y mostrar en pantalla el nombre del producto y cual podría ser su precio de venta en base al calculo de su precio promedio mas la ganancia del 30%, generar esta lista solo para los productos de 3 proveedores

```
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_carritofarma |
+------------------------+
| carrito                |
| ciudad                 |
| cliente                |
| colonia                |
| cuenta                 |
| detallecarrito         |
| estado                 |
| pago                   |
| persona                |
| precio                 |
| producto               |
| proveedor              |
| resurtir               |
| seccion                |
| seccionprod            |
| status                 |
| vaparece               |
| vcarpagado             |
| vlistado               |
| vpagado                |
+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta consulta te podria ayudar, deberias mostrar las tablas de tu base de datos para tener mas detalle de lo que necesitas.

Esta consulta muestre el nombre del producto, el promedio de compra del producto, y el promedio + 30% que seria la ganacia, espero haberte ayudado.

```
SELECT p.Nom_Producto,AVG(precio) as 'Promedio',AVG(p.Precio) + AVG(p.Precio)*0.3 as 'Promedio + 30% (Ganancia)' FROM productos p WHERE p.Nom_Producto = 'Aceite'
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco, ya agrege las tablas en la pregunta, probare tu consulta, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: `avg(p.precio) * 1.3` 